# Flash Pro wont publish Adobe AIR file to USB connected iOS device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

Working with Adobe FLash Professional, using AIR 13.0 for iOS. Haven't updated anything or made any radical changes to the app, but just of late when I try to use Post Publishing to install the app to USB connected  iPad Mini I get this error:

"Unable to install the application. More than one device is connected"

Tried turning off bluetooth, restarting Flash, unplugging and reconnecting the iPad, still getting the same error message. There are no other devices connected to the computer (MacBook Pro circa 2012).

App works fine if I publish the ipa, upload to Testflight, and install from there, but it's slowing down development not being able to publish directly to the device. TIA

Comment: Should update your air sdk to current.  Not having everything up to date can cause issues.

Comment: Good point moot. I've updated to 16.0.0.292. Still getting the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: You can put the .ipa file on the ipad yourself.  It's a little quirky but copy/paste the ipa to itunes then install to ipad.